# How to create a process that runs a script until another process ends

Tags: scripting, process, python

I want to monitor the power that my system needs when i run a Benchmark. When the Benchmark ends the  monitoring process should be killed . The monitor script is written in python. How do i do that?

Comment: `your_monitoring_command & m_pid=$!; wait <benchmark_pid>; kill $m_pid`

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a script to kick off the python power monitoring and the benchmark; when the benchmark process is complete, the script kills off the python process:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# start Python power monitor; sample code!
python -c 'import time; time.sleep(20)' &
m=$!

# start the Benchmark
./benchmark.sh

# Benchmark is done; kill the monitor
kill "$m"
```